# How to sort the results of `find` alphabetically and topologically?

Tags: find

Let's say I have the following files laid out like this:

```
$ tree
.
├── 01/
│   ├── example.txt
│   └── foobar.txt
├── 02/
│   └── example.txt
└── 03/
    ├── example.txt
    └── test.txt

3 directories, 5 files
```

I would like `find .` to print out the directories and files in order, topologically (that is directory names before their contents), and within the same directory, alphabetically. Instead, these are the results I get:

```
$ find .
.
./02
./02/example.txt
./01
./01/foobar.txt
./01/example.txt
./03
./03/test.txt
./03/example.txt
```

I would like the output to look like:

```
.
./01
./01/foobar.txt
./01/example.txt
./02
./02/example.txt
./03
./03/example.txt
./03/test.txt
```

I don't want to pipe to `sort` or to any other command, because I would like to process the lines one by one in order before the `find` command completes.

Comment: Considering all this, you might be happier using something like Perl's File::Find module or manually traversing the directories yourself.  Can you motivate the need to "process the lines (files) one by one, alphabetically"?  (Please [edit] the question as needed).

Comment: @JeffSchaller I'm going through a very big collection of photos, and scanning them for private EXIF metadata, and so on. Having the results processed and sorted topologically and alphabetically makes it easier to eyeball the progress. I didn't want to include the use-case in the question, as I'm not interested in how to solve Y in this post, I'm interested in how to solve X.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.

If you want to process the files in a specific order, you must arrange them in that order before starting to process them.

`find` finds the files/directories in whatever order they are in, in the file system (what is often called "directory order", with many filesystems it is mostly influenced by creation date, but if you delete files/directories their place might be reused, so basically you should assume it to be random), and in your case that appears not to be alphabetical order. But the alphabetically first, might be last in the file system, so if you want to process files in alphabetical order you need to read through the whole directory.

To get the result closest to what you want you'll probably have to do a bit of coding. If you scan the top level directory (of your search), you know to scan the '01' directory next, then '02', ..., and while '02' (and the subsequent directories) are being scanned you can start processing the files in '01'. (If your directory structure is more general, generalise as appropriate.)

Comment: Thank you. It looks like `find` from GNU findutils doesn't have an option that does this. But I just noticed that freeBSD's `find` does have an `-s` option that seems to allow sorting (see [`find` manpage for freeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+13.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html))

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `find`, `sort`, and `xargs`:

```
find . -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0r process_the_files
```

`process_the_files` is whatever program or script you would otherwise be running with find's `-exec` option.

This uses NUL as the filename separator all the way through the pipeline (-print0, -z, and -0 options), so is safe to use with filenames containing any valid characters (including spaces, tabs, newlines etc).

If you want to process the list of filenames produces by find (instead of the contents of those files), you can either:

1. use the above as-is, and write your `process_the_files` script so that it iterates over the filename arguments, and not the contents of those files.  Note that xargs may run `process_the_files` more than once if the list of filenames is too big to fit in one command line (which varies from OS to OS, on Linux it's about 2MB).

   BTW, `find ... -exec ... {} +` is limited in the same way by your system's command-line length.
2. skip the `xargs` part of the pipeline and just pipe sort's output into whatever it is you want to do with them - but that **must** be capable of handling NUL-separated input (most GNU tools can, and it's fairly easy to write your own in awk or perl, or even sh - sh variables can't contain NULs but that doesn't matter when you're just using NUL as a separator).   Doing it this way is not limited by the command-line length limit - it can handle any number of filenames from stdin.

Comment: This doesn't actually sort topologically. Consider what happens if my example also had the directory `01a`. When I try it, it lists `./01`, then `./01a`, then `./01/example.txt` .

Comment: Also, I'm hoping to find a command-line option of `find`. I don't want to pipe to `sort` as I would like to start processing the results before `find` completes.

Comment: 1. find doesn't do sorting.  It's easy to argue that it should (i certainly think it would be useful), but the fact is that it doessn't.  2. because of point 1, you're going to have to pipe find's output into something that sorts it into the way that you want.  If GNU sort can't do what you want, then write your own sort program.  3. pipelines run in parallel - when you pipe from find to other programs, all processes are started at once and run simultaneously.   Unfortunately, sort complicates that sort only produces output once it has read and sorted all of its input, so xargs has to wait.

Comment: Or follow @ JeffSchaller's suggestion and write a script using perl's [File::Find](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Find).  BTW, you mentioned in a comment that you want to process EXIF data in images.  perl's [Image::ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) library module can read and write exif data (this isn't a core perl library, so you'd have to install it via your distro's package manager - e.g. on debian, `apt-get install libimage-exiftool-perl` - or install it with `cpan`).